# Why do text/info boxes not disappear?

Tags: windows-7, display, graphics-card

In Windows 7, I'll occasionally get floating text/info boxes that won't disappear from the screen after popping up, even if the program they appeared from is downsized or even closed.

Why does this happen, and how do I fix without having to reboot?

NOTES

For example, in the attached example below, these info boxes appear if the mouse hovers over the respective buttons in Firefox. But the boxes haven't disappeared, and are still seen even when Firefox is minimized (shown appearing on top of a Windows explorer folder).

This issue is program independent, and not just tied to Firefox.

[image: floating boxes]

Comment: Latest display drivers installed? Have you patched uxtheme.dll to install third party themes? What other customizations have you done (I see extra buttons at the top right of the window)? Try undoing all those changes.

Comment: Latest display drivers are installed, and this issue has been occurring across many months of differing drivers. No uxtheme patching at all. The buttons you see are addons/toolbars in Firefox, and not the operating system. However, these info/text boxes get "burned" into the screen from other programs/places, not just the browser. Which leads me to think it's an OS issue.